# Upload multiple files as a property of a custom class

Tags: c#, ajax

How can i send multiple files as a property to a custom class using ajax call?

I added  `public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }` as a property to my class and I assigned multiple files to this property in ajax call, but my server code only receives a single file that too when is assign

`formdata.append("files", $scope.Files[0]);`

```
 var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("AccountId", $scope.Accountguid);
                    formData.append("DocumentType", 45);
                    formData.append("IsActive", true);
                    formData.append("files", $scope.Files);
                try {
                    $http({
                        url: _APPLocation + "CRM/Carrier/saveDocument",
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": undefined
                        },
                        data: formData
                    }).then(function (response) {

                    }, function (error) {
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    //alert(e);
                }
```

Comment: What does 
`server code only receives a single file that too when is assign`
mean

Comment: /Carrier/saveDocument - Server method

Comment: I'm not that expert but I know that we've had problems with files too and send them as an array of Base64 encoded strings from and to our backend.

Comment: base64 from client side that too for multiple files, will be slow process plus we will have restriction on size or can you please elaborate?

Comment: What's `value`? Can you add your server code to the question? Is there a reason why you are passing `"Content-Type"` as `undefined`?

Comment: sorry that's not value, that's the file scope, i changed it

Comment: since i m sending both file and data in single object I kept the content type as undefined.   public JsonResult saveDocument(BO.CRM.CarrierDocument doc)
        { return Json({});}